# ES6 double destructure

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I understand this probably is a pretty basic question, but I'm not proficient with ES6 and I've encountered this syntax:

```
const { rootStore: { routerStore } } = this.props;
```

I understand what something like this means:

```
const { rootStore } = this.props;
```

(Creating a const `rootStore` from the property `rootStore` in `this.props`).

But what does the above double deconstruction (I assume it's deconstruction) mean?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This is called nested destructuring, and it's very useful in many situations.

Let's understand it bit by bit.

Look at this example:

```js
const person = {
    friend: {
        name: 'john',
        age: 20,
    },
};

const { friend } = person;

console.log(friend);
```

Here we get the value of the prop `friend` using destructuring. Since the value itself is an object, we can use destructuring with it as well.

From the previous example:

```js
const person = {
    friend: {
        name: 'john',
        age: 20,
    },
};

const { friend } = person;

console.log(friend);

const {age} = friend ;

console.log(age) ;
```

Now we get the `age` prop using destructuring as well, and that's pretty and super handy, but what if I just need the `age` prop and I don't need the `friend` prop? Can I do all the above example in one step? Yes!! and that's the awesomeness of ES6:

```js
const person = {
    friend: {
        name: 'john',
        age: 20,
    },
};

const { friend :{age} } = person;

console.log(age);
```

As you can see, we get the value of `age` in one step, and that's useful in many situations when you have nested objects. In the code above, if you try to log the value of `friend` you'll get `ReferenceError: friend is not defined`.

Did you know? You can make nested destructuring as deep as you want. Look at this complex  example which is just for fun.

```js
const person = {
    friend: {
        name: 'john',
        other: {
            friend: {
                name: {
                    fullName: {
                        firstName: 'demo',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
};

const {
    friend: {
        other: {
            friend: {
                name: {
                    fullName: { firstName },
                },
            },
        },
    },
} = person;

console.log(firstName); // demo
```

Pretty!!

If you want to know more about destructuring take a look at these resources:

[Destructuring assignment MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

[Destructuring and parameter handling in ECMAScript 6](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html)

Answer (score 5):

It means

```
const {rootStore} = this.props
const {routerStore} = rootStore
```

Except the first line will not effect, which is `rootStore` will not be defined.

Comment: in your code it defines two constants `rootStore` and `routerStore` but in `const { rootStore: { routerStore } } = this.props;` it only defines one constant `routerStore`

Answer (score 5):

`const { rootStore: { routerStore } } = this.props;`

Just to add my part, the above code actually means the following

`const { routerStore } = this.props.rootStore;`

not the following:

```
const {rootStore} = this.props
const {routerStore} = rootStore
```

the difference is that the first one only defines one constant `routerStore` whereas the second one defines two constants `rootStore` and `routerStore`. so there is little difference.

Answer (score 1):

When destructuring an object, the part on the left side of the colon is the property name and the part on the right side is what the property value is destructured into. (Shorthand works as it does in an object literal, where `{ x }` is equivalent to `{ x: x }`.) This target is declared or assigned to according to where the destructuring appears:

```
const { x: y } = z;
// equivalent to:
const y = z.x;
```

```
let { x: y } = z;
// equivalent to:
let y = z.x;
```

```
({ x: y }) = z;
// equivalent to:
y = z.x;
```

where `y` can be another pattern. So this:

```
const { rootStore: { routerStore } } = this.props;
```

is equivalent to:

```
const { routerStore } = this.props.rootStore;
```

which is also how I would write it if only using the one property. You can read the colon as “into” if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It separates `routerStore` from

```
this.props.rootStore.routerStore
```

by taking nested objects for a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).