# Double Destructuring when main object may be undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, react-apollo

First all my question is not rehash of [ES6 double destructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999968/es6-double-destructure)

Look at the following code - Apollo Client GraphQL

```
import { gql, useQuery, useMutation } from '@apollo/client';
...
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(TREATMENTS);
```

It would be nicer to write it this way:

```
   const { loading, error, data : {treatments} } = useQuery(TREATMENTS);
```

However, unfortunately I've got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'treatments' of undefined
TreadDetails
C:/Users/albertly/Downloads/git/individual-claims/src/TreatDetails.tsx:35

  32 | `;
  33 | 
  34 | function TreadDetails(): React.ReactElement {
> 35 |   const { loading, error, data : {treatments} } = useQuery(TREATMENTS);
  36 |  // const [treatments, setTreatments] = useState<Treatment[]>([]);
  37 |   const { state: stateApp, dispatch: dispatchApp } = useContext(AppContext);
```

I understand perfectly well why it is happening.

My question is: Is there some syntactical trick to make it work ?

**Edited:**
It has been brought to my attention that there is a quite similar question
[Destructuring with nested objects and default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049399/destructuring-with-nested-objects-and-default-values)

Comment: The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049399/destructuring-with-nested-objects-and-default-values - "Destructuring with nested objects and default values"  does answer my question. Although my question is more specific I would  figure out what to do if I found this answer and I wouldn't ask it. When I tried to delete this question I've got a system suggestion that deleting is not recommended. What to do?

Comment: May be it's better to leave it as is (without status duplicate) because it may be helpful to community - the problem is more clear in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide an initial value for `data` to destructure from.

```
const { loading, error, data: { treatments } = {} } = useQuery(TREATMENTS);
```